# Making a ravendb unit test fail

Tags: unit-testing, ravendb

I'm working on a project with RavenDB (awesome product by the way), and am trying to bite the bullet and actually have unit and integration tests for my code from the get-go. My first set of tests are just basic sanity tests to see if my code can actually connect to the database, as I want to see if my connect code and environment for testing are actually configured properly. I try to have set of tests like this in case things really go belly up later, that way I can determine if I did something dumb at a lower level.

I'm creating a DocumentStore and then initializing a session off of it. Apparently, even if the database itself doesn't exist on the server, the code thus far in the process will still work without an error. How can I actually test that I can connect to a working database with this thing? Should I just fake up a document and attempt to shove it in there or am I missing a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will,
I am not sure that I understand what you mean. You want to see that you can get a failure from trying to access a non existant database?
In that case, here is something that would throw:

```
using(var store = new DocumentStore{Url = "http://localhost:8080"}.Initialize())
using(var session = store.OpenSession("Database-Name-That-Does-Not-Exist"))
{
    session.Load<object>("some-doc-id");

}
```

Comment: I ended up just opening a session and then trying to get the statistics for the database. That threw when the database didn't exist and went smoothly when it did. Basically, I was trying to create a suite of tests to help with troubleshooting later when I break the whole thing (for instance, when I move to another machine and don't have the database there). It's just to reduce the amount of time I spend pulling my hair trying to figure out what I screwed up.

I'd like to point out to you though, that my tests of getting stuff in and out were easy and painless. Everything works darned well.